# Updating Spring xml configured controller to Annotations

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

I have been tasked with updating a old project that I did not write.

The project is Spring MVC based and has an older Spring Controller configuration that I am unfamiliar with.

The controllers have bean configurations as follows

```
<bean id="controllerName" class="the.project.controller.class">
<property name"serviceName">
  <ref bean="serviceName">
 </property>
<property name"successView">
  <value>viewName</value>
 </property>
</bean>
```

where serviceName refers to a class annotated with `@Service` as follows

```
  @Service(value=serviceName)
```

Is this the correct replacement for the xml configuration ?

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("serviceName")
ServiceNameImpl serviceName
```

thanks

edit here is the organization of the serviceName class and interface

```
  public interface ServiceName {
   // methods omitted
 }

 @Service(value="serviceName")
 public class ServiceNameImpl implments ServiceName {
 //methods omitted
 }
```

The @Resource annotation is not available to me  ( Spring 3.0.7) and Autowire as above fails (  as it appears the type is not as expected as described below )

```
  org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching beans of type [the.project.ServiceNameImpl] found for dependency
```

Given the edits, what am I doing wrong here ( Apologies for leaving out this information )?

in the end I need to be able to access the methods of the interface and its implementation

for example

```
serviceName.doSomething(someVar);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's correct, but consider using `private` modifier for `serviceName`. Another way would be to use `@Resource`:

```
@Resource
private ServiceNameClass serviceName;
```

Note that in this case you don't need a `@Qualifier("serviceName")` - `@Resource` autowires by (field) name while `@Autowired` uses type by default. Only a problem when you have several beans of the same/compatible type.

Also you can skip the `controllerName` bean definition altogether by annotating controller class with `@Controller`.

BTW you can also shorten the XML configuration a bit by using the following syntax:

```
<bean id="controllerName" class="the.project.controller.class">
    <property name"serviceName" ref="serviceName"/>
    <property name"successView" value="viewName"/>
</bean>
```

(IntelliJ suggests this transformation and performs it for you).

Comment: Tomasz I appear to have left out important information. If you have a moment could you examine and update your answer ? Thanks very much . The goal here is to eliminate as much xml configuration as possible and this is the last one .

Comment: @stimpy: The field mus be of type `ServiceName`: `ServiceName serviceName`. BTW with Spring 3.1 you can get away with no XML at all!

Comment: I updated the question with more detail. Apologies for the extra laps.